# .remove() is removing elements from both variables (lists) (which I set equal to each other) when I only want to remove it from one variable

Tags: python, function, variables, nonetype

I have a list called `ranks` and a list called `modelRanks`, they are equal. When I iterate through my for loop I want to remove anything from `modelRanks` that has a count of 2 or more in `ranks`. I used the `remove` function and it is removing the element from both when I call it to only remove from `modelRanks`.

I've also tried `modelRanks = modelRanks.remove(num)` and `modelRanks -= [num]`

This is my code currently. I am using python 3.7.

```
def modelForPairs(ranks):

    modelRanks = ranks

    for num in ranks:
        count = ranks.count(num)

        if count > 1:
            modelRanks.remove(num)

    return modelRanks
```

If my list of ranks is `[11, 2, 3, 11, 3]`, I want my `modelRanks` to end up looking like `[2]`. If `ranks = [2, 4, 3, 11, 3]` I want `modelRanks` to end up looking like `[2, 4, 11]` and etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, just change the line `modelRanks = ranks` to `modelRanks = ranks.copy()`.

In Python, setting a variable equal to a list just points it to that list object; it does not create a copy by default. For example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst2 = lst
lst2.remove(2)
print(lst2)
# [1, 3]
print(lst)
# [1, 3]
# They're the same object!
```

You can get around this by explicitly calling `lst.copy()` or `lst[:]` ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)). Both of these perform what's called a *shallow copy*.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst2 = lst.copy()  # or lst2 = lst[:]
lst2.remove(2)
print(lst2)
# [1, 3]
print(lst)
# [1, 2, 3]
# Different objects!
```

A note on *shallow* vs. *deep* copies (because I see a lot of evidence that there is some confusion on this point). From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html):

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for
>   compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or
>   class instances):
>
> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
>     extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>     the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
>     inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Basically if your list contains other objects, and you explicitly need to avoid just pointing to the *same* objects in the *new* list, then and only then do you need to use a deep copy. A shallow copy will populate a *new* list with pointers to the *same* objects. Removing items from this list will not affect the original objects in any way, and will only remove them from the *new* list.

A deep copy will create entirely new objects, recursively, for everything in your list. This is often unnecessary, but it's good to be aware of the distinction for cases where you, for instance, want to copy items into a new list and *manipulate* only those items in the new list, not the original items from where they were copied.

If none of that made sense to you, don't worry about it. You may run into some headaches in the future with copying lists, in which case remember to look in to deep vs. shallow copies.

Answer (score 1):

or simply use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(ranks)
modelRanks = list(item for item, count in c.items() if count == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use deepcopy while initializing :

Replace

```py
modelRanks = ranks
```

with

```py
modelRanks = copy.deepcopy(ranks)
```

Also `import copy` before running the module.

Answer (score 0):

In your first line: (modelRanks = ranks)
you are doing shallow copy.
That means both variables point to same location in memory. Thus when you change one variable, change is also visible trough second variable.

To make deep copy of list use [copy.deepcopy(...)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) and your second variable will have own memory space.

Comment: Technically incorrect. He isn't copying at all, he's just pointing to the same object with a different name. `list.copy()` or `arr[:]` (my examples) perform shallow copies, which give you a new list of all of the elements of the old list. In the case of arrays of objects, use deep copy, but for basic arrays, shallow is fine.

Answer (score 0):

So what's happening here is that when you set the two lists equal to each other, you are copying the reference of the first variable to the second.

Here's what I mean: 
Assume an array is assigned to `a`. When we write the expression `b = a`, then `b` points to the same array as `a`.
So a diagram for this might look like:
[image: Diagram]
What this means is that if `a` changes, then `b` will also change. Thus, we must create a copy of list `a` if we want to not change `b` by using the `a.copy()` method.

Comment: thank you! this helped me understand what i was doing wrong

Comment: @Maggie If the answer solved your problem, then you should accept it as the best answer (the checkmark) :)